# Matplotlib: How to format float values for plt.xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a Seaborn boxplot with xticks that I am trying to format. Currently they look like the image below:

[image]

However, I want to have a tick at every 0.01 interval.

I tried `plt.xticks(range(-0.3,0.3,0.01))`, however I am getting an error that reads

> 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Which I believe is because I cannot use float values with `range()`. Any idea on how I can bypass this?

Comment: [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) can handle floats

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that

> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either built-in
> int or any object that implements the **index** special method).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges

The easiest way to achieve what you want is probably to use a Numpy function (as you have matplotlib, you have numpy installed for sure)

```
import numpy as np
np.linspace(-0.3, 0.3, int(0.6/0.01))
```

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html